# How to ignore @Scheduled annotations in test

Tags: scheduled-tasks

I am testing a complex component which has several @Scheduled annotations, and when testing my component, I want to ignore these "timers" -- is it possible to disable this @Scheduled annotation from within a test ?

Comment: so far the only solution was to comment out - however I was hoping for a more dynamic approach